# Is it advisable to mention the dollar amount for grants on a CV?

Tags: postdocs, cv, funding

I'm a soon-to-be post-doc and am currently sending my resumes to people and applying to places. 4 years ago, I applied for a grant and got funding for 3 years for *everything* — meaning my tuition, pay, research, travel expenses, university overhead and then some more, all of which totals to a large $ amount.

My question is: Is it advisable to put the actual $ amount on the CV (to show I'm capable of getting and handling funds) or would that seem like showing off? I've seen some people (usually folks with more experience) list it, but they're also ones that have won several grants and fundings, so there's stuff to list. In my case, this is the only thing so I'm afraid of it standing out and attracting unwanted attention.

Comment: If you mention the details of what the grant covered (like you did for this question), that would imply that the grant wasn't trivial without going into dollar amounts - so, how have you described the grant in your CV?

Comment: @TCSGrad Right now, I've just listed it as a "Funding to research X from sponsor Y" without going into any details (I know, it's terrible)

Comment: I recommend listing it in the same way as an experienced researcher would, except your list has only one entry and his has many. SO: sponsor organization name, official name of the grant, grant ID number from the sponsor, starting and ending dates, etc. plus a brief abstract of the work, and references to your grant's deliverables.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're applying for academic jobs in the US, your ability to acquire funding is one component of your viability as an academic. So definitely add in the information about the amount of money. It will stand out (in a good way)

Comment: I would add a caveat to this - "as long as the amounts aren't trivial".