# List dollar amount of small grants on C.V.?

Tags: cv, funding

This is related to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7316/is-it-advisable-to-mention-the-dollar-amount-for-grants-on-a-cv), but I don't believe a duplicate since the dollar amount there was impressive, whereas mine are not.

I have been awarded several intra-University small grants ($2-4k each), about one a year, during my Ph.D.  These were funds to cover research expenses, rather than to cover my stipend, and I believe I've used them productively.

Should I list the dollar amounts of these on my C.V.?  On the one hand, listing them shows they're not just honorary amounts.  On the other, the amounts are not enormous either, and there are all the usual disadvantages of listing (setting the wrong tone, etc.).  Plus it just makes me a little uneasy.

Background here is: headed into a soft money position eventually, and my stipend is fully covered without conditions, so I've had no need to apply for any of the big extramural grants.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would say yes. I have done so from when I received my first grant/stipend. I ceased listing once I received a permanent position (or thereabouts) and started getting multiyer grants from national sources.

As long as you think adding it shows that you are active and competitive (well merited) in terms of receiving the trust to receive money it will be a good thing. You need to constantly evaluate the possible pros and cons of adding informaton to your cv, including funding. I would imagine that being in a soft money situation, listing funding will only be a positive. But, be aware that gaps in your funding stream may become question marks unless they are explicitly explained.

Comment: IMHO, yes. It is how professional researchers do, you're early stage and small amounts should not cause you to deviate from that. It helps show you are a researcher.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on who the CV is going to. In most cases, I would think that listing dollar amounts leaves the wrong impression: first, that your primary thought is of money, and second that you're not very good at it. It is probably more impressive sounding, in general, if you list the award, the donor, the purpose. For example, the "Susan B. Lovemoney award for student creativity" is more impressive sounding than "$1K departmental stipend." Let the reader imagine that you might have received some large amount of money, and if they ask, say that it was a modest amount, enough to enable you to accomplish your research goals.

Comment: I disagree. First, getting funding of any amount as a PhD student is impressive. Second, the purpose of the CV is not to mislead people about how impressive something is.

Comment: The purpose of a CV is to tell why you are the right person for the job at hand. I was not suggesting misleading but your CV is part of your person story, leaving out information in a CV is part of telling the story well.