# Is it appropriate to include dollar amounts for awards granted when applying to a math PHD?

Tags: mathematics, cv

This question includes REU (research experience for undegraduates) grant, travel grants, or prizes awarded. I've seen a friend's CV and he seemed to do this. I was wondering if this is to be expected or if one should refrain from posting the amount awarded.

Perhaps it is worth mentioning that participation in an REU (and the support received) does not really belong in a "grants, honors, and awards" section, or at least that is my impression.

There is a [similar question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7316/is-it-advisable-to-mention-the-dollar-amount-for-grants-on-a-cv) on this website, but I'm asking specifically about  applying for graduate school and what is culturally accepted among the mathematics community in the United States

Comment: I'm not in math, so just a comment. But yes, I usually see dollar values (I have them on my CV, and no, I would be surprised to see an REU in such a section, but I also never had one so idk. Maybe better to have two questions

Comment: @AzorAhai I'm in math, and I don't usually see dollar amounts on students' CVs.

Comment: This seems like the kind of thing which would vary between geographical cultures as well as subject cultures, so it might be worth editing the question to state the geographical culture of interest.

Comment: @PeterTaylor agreed. Edited the last sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is entirely your choice -- doesn't hurt, but not necessary either.

Readers of grad school applications generally have a decent idea of how much REU or travel grants (a couple of thousand dollars) and how much departmental awards are worth (a few hundred dollars, typically). So not stating a number is not a big deal. Stating a number also doesn't hurt: if it's within the range a reader would expect, then there is no harm done, space is cheap; if the dollar amount is surprisingly large -- say, a $5,000 award for your work, then that's useful knowledge and should have been on your CV indeed.

Comment: That is fair, I meant to mention that as well: all standard amounts of money (save maybe one such grant.) thanks